# How to properly uninstall TWS (Trader Workstation) by Interactive Brokers from Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, uninstallation, interactive-brokers, tws

I guess everything is in the title.

They do have an installation shell script but nothing else. I was looking for any other scripts or, maybe, some CLI flags to make it perform an uninstall but couldn't find any.

How does one properly uninstall this stuff?

Answer (score 17):

Inside ~/Jts I found an uninstall script.  Run ./uninstall, then remove the Jts directory.

Answer (score 10):

I found an uninstall script in ~/Applications/Trader Workstation and ran that.
Deleted the empty directory ~/Applications/Trader Workstation and ~/Jts

Answer (score 4):

For myself, MacOS BigSur, with TWS version 10.*.

1. Uninstall via `~/Applications/Trader Workstation/Uninstall.app`
2. Remove both `~/Applications/Trader Workstation` and `~/Jts`

Answer (score 3):

I wrote to IB about this and their answer is below.  I'm not a client. I was just looking at them again. I don't like not knowing more about it, but I'll try the post below.

> Dear Client,
>
> Thank you for contacting Interactive Brokers. I apologize for the
>   delayed response.
>
> Unfortunately, we do not have any official documentation on this. You
>   will have to do a search on the Internet for the instructions on how
>   to uninstall a application using Linux.
>
> I apologize for any inconvenience and appreciate your understanding.
>
> Regards,
>
> Almir B. Technical Assistance Center Interactive Brokers

Comment: I find it quite interesting that they don't even know how to uninstall ... However nevertheless this is not an answer to the question how TWS can get uninstalled ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found the shell script ~/Jts/978/uninstall, 
978 being the installed version.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting directory `~/Jts` will be enough under Linux.
But this will not delete the user settings, because they are uploaded on remote server and will be applied again after re-install.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 uninstall.sh in ~/Jts/979 .

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the TWS with macOS but I think because of the UNIX-base it's the same as linux distributions:

Because of its java core it's not spreaded like some other applications. All files in the `~/Jts` directory and the execution files in `~/Applications/`.

Answer (score 0):

The script `uninstall` is no longer in `~/Jts`, it's located in the installion directory `tws` - **Trader Workstation** creates by default, you could also change the path in which the directory will be created.

- `uninstall` doesn't remove neither `~/Jts` or `tws`, make sure to remove them by yourself.